# Show that for a prime $p$, the polynomial $x^p+a$ in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ is not irreducible for any $a \in \mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here's my attempt:

$\mathbb Z_p[x]$ is an integral domain with characteristic $p$ for a prime $p$.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^p+a$. So $a=-\alpha^p$

Then the polynomial becomes $x^p-\alpha^p=(x-\alpha)^p$

So it is not irreducible.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks just fine...but why would $\;\alpha\in\Bbb F_p\;$ ?? This follows from the fact that $\;x\mapsto x^p\;$ is *an automorphism* of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ . Check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, provided you recall that $a^p=a$, for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, by Fermat's little theorem.

I would say, then, $x^p+a=x^p+a^p=(x+a)^p$, that's simpler.

Note that the same is true if you use any finite field $F$ of characteristic $p$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed the map
$$
a\mapsto a^p
$$
is a field homomorphism $F\to F$, so it's injective and therefore it's also surjective by finiteness of $F$